# Weak convergence of measures is equivalent to convergence in Wasserstein distance

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence, optimal-transport

Weak convergence of measures on a measurable space $X$, denoted $\mu_n \xrightarrow{w} \mu$, is defined as
$$ \int f d\mu_n \rightarrow \int fd\mu \;\;\;\; \text{ for all } f\in C_b(X)$$ where $C_b(X)$ is the set of continuous, bounded functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I read that **weak convergence is equivalent to convergence in 2-Wasserstein distance** (optimal transport distance); the distance is given by $$W_2(\mu_n, \mu) = \inf_{p\in P(\mu_n,\mu)} \int c(x,y)^2 dp(dx dy)$$ where $P(\mu_n,\mu)$ is the set of probability measures with $\mu_n, \mu$ as marginals, and $c$ is a 'cost' pairing, $c: X\times X \rightarrow[0,\infty)$.

I'm trying to figure out why weak convergence and convergence in $W_2$ distance are equivalent. I guess $f$ and $c$ can be treated the same, but $f$ has to be continuous and bounded whereas $c$ simply has to be nonnegative. I don't see how $\int fd\mu_n - \int f d\mu \rightarrow 0$ implies $W_w(\mu_n,\mu) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: In general, what you wrote down is not a metric (depending on $c$). To get a metric you want $c$ to be a metric (and there is a square missing on the left side). Even then, it is in general not true that weak convergence implies convergence in $W_2$ distance, only if the underlying metric space is bounded.

Comment: Please see Theorem 6.8 ($W_p$ metrizes $P_p$) of Optimal Transport Old and New.

Comment: @MaoWao, It's been almost a year :). But I have a question about the last part you mentioned. Is there any proof for that. I think the only point is that to show weak convergence implies the convergence of second moment, which in general is not true. But it may be true for bounded metric space? Thanks!

Comment: @Rostam22 Exactly, convergence with respect to $W_2$ is equivalent to weak convergence plus convergence of the second moments (Daniel Adams's comment gives a reference). If the metric space is bounded, then $x\mapsto d(x,x_0)^2$ is bounded (and continuous), so convergence of the second moment follows from weak convergence.